# Can't Link grass to remote server postgis topology schema for import or export vector data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, grass-7.0

I have installed postgre/postgis on a remote server in which i want add topology data from Grass Gis to postgre topology schema.

Grass gis 7.2.1 is installed on another PC on the network which has access to the postgis database through Qgis 2.8.11.

i was wondering how can i add postgis databse connection to the Grass gis 7.2.1 so i can use that connection for importing and exporting vector layer?

Without a configured connection i get this error while trying to define an output format:

[image]

In all videos i searched i see examples with already linked to postgis, and i don't know how to link it to my database.

This is the log in log i get:

"*(Mon Aug 21 10:35:49 2017)

db.login --overwrite driver=pg database=postgres user=postgres password=xxxx host=localhost port=5433
WARNING: DB connection  already exists and will be overwritten
The password was stored in file (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\dblogin)
(Mon Aug 21 10:35:49 2017) Command finished (0 sec)*"